# In regard to delivery

Tags: word-usage

Can I say we need the delivery of this order tomorrow?
Is it the same meaning as the following sentence？

We need this order to be delivered tomorrow.

If there is any other way to put it, please advise me, thanks.

Comment: You can omit _to be_: We need this order delivered tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with saying "we need the delivery of this order tomorrow" but your own second construction "we need this order to be delivered tomorrow" is the more formal and grammatically correct version.

Comment: Though depending on the context, "we require delivery" may be considered more formal or polite than "we need delivery".

Answer (score -2):

We need this order to be delivered by tomorrow